# Configuring Google App Engine instance behaviour via app.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a fairly simple application deployed using Google App Engine which make use of the PHP runtime. I'm currently looking to ensure that a minimum of one instance remains active at all times. To do this, I've tried adding the following settings to `app.yaml`:

```
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

However, upon deploying my changes via the command line I'm warned:

> WARNING: Performance settings included in this update are being
>   ignored because your application is not using the Modules feature. See
>   the Modules documentation for more information. Python:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) Java:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) Go:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/modules/) PHP:
>   (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/).

It's my understanding that all Google App Engine applications are deployed with a default module, and that `app.yaml` acts as the configuration point for that module. As my application is fairly simple I don't have a need for multiple modules and, as such, am simply looking to tweak instance behaviour across the whole of my application.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have a `module: default` in your app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the modules were introduced, the instance class and other related settings were configured vie [App Engine Console](https://appengine.google.com/). Go to **Administration** / **Application Settings** and check section **Performance**. However, I am not sure if it is still available since now the console is superseded by [Google Develpers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and there is no such an option available.

Based on the warning message you get, it seems that your application does not follow App Engine directory layout required for modules. Try to check documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Configuration).

There is one more thing to consider.

> If you’ve changed any of the frontend performance settings in the Admin Console, you can’t upload module files until you’ve migrated manually. A section titled **Performance Settings Migration for Modules** appears in the Admin Console below the Performance section.

Comment: I'm nervous when it comes to using the old Performance settings because the documentation mentions it's been superseded. Regarding using app.yaml for configuration: that's what I'm having issues with. As my original post states, I can't seem to configure instance scaling via app.yaml.

Comment: Check your directory layout. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I had looked over the diagram previously, and am following the second example (where all application files are in the same directory). Currently, however, I have no dispatch.yaml file (this seemed redundant in my case, as everything should be routed to the default module).

Comment: I've never set Performance Settings via the Admin Console, and as such the migration settings don't appear for me. To clarify, the only configuration file I have for my project is app.yaml, and any other settings changes I've made have been through the Google Developers Console.

Comment: Did adjusting directory layout help to solve your issue?

Comment: How would you suggest adjusting the layout? From what I can see, I'm doing what the docs suggest: placing everything in a single folder. It seems like the multiple folder structure works best for more modular applications. But at this point I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Do I get it right that you have all application files in the same directory as per documentation and you still get the same error?